# alert box from a service

Tags: android, service

I am runing a service in my application which is polling a remote servlet , but what i noticed when i kept the server stop where servlet is located , application getting close unexpectedly.
Here's the code

```
try {
                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpGet("http://192.168.1.42:8080/NotifyServlet/serv");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I want that when server is stopped , it should show an alert box i do not know if it is possible to show alert box from a service.Can any one suggest me what to do?
Thanks

Comment: If you found this answer as a correct then upVote it or mark as a correct answer. So it helps you and other user also.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pop-up alert box (alert dialog) from the service, then I think you have to **start a Activity with alert dialoge theme**.

In your activity's manifest.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to **just pop-up Toast**, then no need to start activity,

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: ok..you mean to say in the catch block , i should start another activity.

Comment: When server is stop what response you are get just use that response and make a condition on it and in that block start a activity.